# Async profiling nodejs server to review the code?

Tags: node.js, performance, optimization, asynchronous, profiling

We encountered performance problem on our nodejs server holding 100k ip everyday.
Now we want to review the code and find the bottle-neck.
@jfriend00 from what we can see now, the problem seems to be DB access and file access. But we don't know what logic caused this access.

We are still looking for good ways to do the async profiling of nodejs server.

### Here's what we tried

#### [Nodetime](http://nodetime.com/)

This works for us to some extent. It can give the executing time of code specified to the lines. However, we can't locate the error because the server works async and no stacking and calling info can be determined.

#### [Async-profiling](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/async-profile)

This works with async and is said to be the first of this kind.
Problem is, we've integrated it's js code with our server-side code.

```
var AsyncProfile = require('async-profile')

AsyncProfile.profile(function () {

    ///// OUR SERVER-SIDE CODE RESIDES HERE
    setTimeout(function () {
        // doAsyncStuff
    });

});
```

We can only record the profile of one time of server execution for one request. Can we use this code with things like `forever`? I've no idea with this.

#### dtrace

This is too general for us to locate problem in nodejs code.

Do you have any idea on profiling nodejs server code? Any hints or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A profiling solution is usually targeted at exactly what the performance problem is that you're trying to troubleshoot.  Can you describe what performance problem it is that you're having?

Comment: @jfriend00 edited. The problem seems to be BD access.

Comment: You're still not telling us as much as you could.  When you say the issue is with DB access, what exact symptoms are you observing that lead you to this conclusion?  Do you know how long each DB request is taking and how many requests you're making?  What are you using for a DB as many DBs have some diagnostic capabilities built in?  Same questions for file access.